# How to send email to many users without triggering abuse reports?

Tags: php, windows, email, vps

I have a Windows VPS and this script runs from my VPS.

I wrote this script to send one email to all of my users. I have 6000 users in my site. If I run this script I know I will be regarded as sending spam by my data center, and I will receive abuse emails from my DC.

```
<?php
    require_once('load.php');
    $stmt  = $db->query("SELECT email FROM user");
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $subject = "subject";
    $sendsubject= "=?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($subject)."?=";
    $mail->Subject = $sendsubject;
    $mail->Body =   'mail body here';


    foreach($rows as $row){
    $mail->AddAddress($row);
    $mail->Send();
    }

?>
```

I need a way to send 200 emails per hour. Any way with PHP?

Comment: The important thing is not how you send email, it is how you came by your email address database in the first place. If you bought it, or you scraped the web for them, or otherwise don't have (genuine) double opt-in records for your particular use case, throw the database away.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a service provider for this kind of email?

there are a lot of them and 6000 emails should be in the free usage of a few of them.
for example http://www.mailjet.com/

Comment: this site is 200 email per day

Comment: The free plan is capped at 200 emails per day but we do have an affordable paying plan if you wish. I would suggest going with the bronze offer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use php mailer and send it via ajax fetching one at a time.It will take time but spam free

Comment: good idea ill try this way

Comment: If this is intended to slow email sending down, that's a good start, but sending in AJAX requests is a long-winded way to go about it. Much better to send in a cron process with a `sleep()` between sending each one. Of course, we don't know if the OP even _should_ be sending email to these addresses yet - perhaps the problem is in fact that those email users have not subscribed to his service.

Comment: he can always divide his 200 recepients into 4 50s and add javascript timer after each 50.I have done this and thats why i m proposing it.And about the email ops and their acceptance thats different.Each provider has their own terms and conditions.He has to beg infront of hotmail :) for their acceptance if he uses his own smtp server.Now please remove the down vote

Comment: "Each [email] provider has their own terms and conditions" - I think that's wrong too. Many countries have various kinds of data protection legislation; here in the UK, we have the Data Protection Act. Each of these items of legislation attempt to give individuals (such as owners of email accounts) control over whether/how their data is stored. Thus, if someone in the UK takes my email address and sells it to a third party for the purposes of spamming, I can take him to court, or register a complaint against him, to discourage him from doing so. This is the advice we should be giving the OP.

Comment: (If you wish to ping me, please use @halfer to do so - otherwise I may not see your message).